# Well posedness of linear Klien-Gordon equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial boundary value problem
$$ u_{tt} = u_{xx} - u$$
for $0 < x < 1, \; 0 < t$ with the initial data
$$ u(x,0) = \phi(x)$$ and $$ u_t(x,0) = \psi(x).$$

Assuming the initial conditions are sufficiently smooth, for which constant values $a,b,c,d$ do the boundary conditions
$$au_x + bu_t = 0 \; \text{ at } x = 0$$
$$cu_x + du_t = 0 \; \text{ at } x = 1$$
lead to a well posed problem?

---

I haven't got much experience in problems such as these, I was hoping for a solution or a push in the right direction.  My instincts tell me that $(ad - bc)$ is probably an important value... but this is just speculation.  Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Look at the energy $E(t) = \int_0^1 u_t^2 + u_x^2 + u^2\, dx$, and figure out when $E'(t)\leq 0$, i.e., the energy is decreasing.

Comment: In this case, looking at the energy suffices because we don't expect our solutions to grow with time, correct? I believe the solution is dispersive waves, does dispersion decrease energy?

Comment: A general principle in PDE is if you can prove energy estimates, then well-posedness will follow. Showing $E(t) \leq E(0)$ will give you uniqueness of solutions, and continuous dependence on initial data. Once you have nice energy estimates like this, existence follows from standard techniques like the Galerkin Method (Evans's PDE Chapter 7).

Comment: Another way of looking at this is to use separation of variables and look for a solution in the form of a Fourier series.